# How to list all followers with their following date?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tweepy

How do you list all followers with their following date of a particular Twitter account through Tweepy?

Comment: Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve a user's followers using [`API.followers`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#API.followers), which uses the [GET followers/list endpoint](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-followers-list).

Unfortunately, Twitter's API does not expose the date/time of when they followed.

Comment: If I had found your article earlier, I wouldn't have wasted time for this solution.